# Creating doubly linked list(DLL) from a basic linked list-Composition or inheritance?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Say my BasicLinkedList(BLL) has these following basic methods:

```
-insert at the head, tail, anywhere
-delete at the head, tail, anywhere
```

---

I want to know if I should use *composition or inheritance* to create my DLL from BLL.

My **thought** process:

My guess was composition from the read up of **Effective Java Item #18(3rd Edition): Favour composition over inheritance**.

But composition didn't feel right here as I didn't know how to incorporate the pointer to previous node with delegation.

Then I read up on **Liskov substitution Principle(LSP)** and seems that inheritance is the right choice? But I'm not sure.

---

Question(summarised):
Should I use *composition or inheritance* to create my DLL from BLL? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Favor composition over inheritance" does not mean you should never use Inheritance and that Inheritance is always bad. In this particular case, you are better off using inheritance to gain access to the necessary class variables and methods.

Comment: So do we not have to worry about exposing the BLL supertype to DLL subtype, ie gaining access to supertype since it fulfills LSP-->Is that why inheritance is "not bad" in this case?

Comment: @foggynight Totally agree. My response was more on the ground that it might simply not be possible to use composition in this case. Moreover, even inheritance might not cut it if members are kept private.